# Help with Set Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that $A$, $B$, $C$, and $Z$ are the following sets:

$$
A=\{x\ne 0  \mid x\text{ is a multiple of a prime number}\}$$

$$
B=\{-100, -99, - 98, \ldots, 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 100\} 
$$

$$
C=\{-x   | x \in A \} 
$$

$$
Z=\{n\mid n\text{ is a whole number}\}$$

Give proof that the following is true:

a)  $A \cup (B \cup C) = Z$

b)  $Z – (A \cup B) = C – B$

c)  $A – (B \cup C) = A – B = A – (A \cap B)$

Comment: The definition of set A is ambiguous. Integer multiples, positive integer multiples, rational multiples, $\dots$?

Comment: Strikes me that $A= \{........, -5,-4,-3,-22,3,4,....\} = $ all  whole numbers except $\pm 1$ and $0$ and that $C = A$.

Comment: I also think that the teacher meant what fleablood said about A.

Comment: just talk it through.  Every whole number in $Z$ is either in $A$ or is equal to $-1,0,1$ and therefore in $B$.  And if it's in B, it is in $B\cup C$.  So every whole number is in $A$ or in $B\cup C$ so every whole number is in $A\cup (B\cup C)$.  And these sets contain nothing *but* whole numbers so every whole number is in $A\cup (B\cup C)$ and $A\cup(B\cup C)$ contains nothing *but* whole numbers, so $A\cup(B\cup C)$ is precisely all the whole numbers.  So $A\cup (B\cup C)   =Z$.  .... and so on.

Comment: b) is false if I was correct about A.  $A\cup B$ contains all whole number so $Z-(A\cup B)$ is empty.  But $C-B$ will contain all whole numbers bigger than $100$ or less than $-100$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Really appreciate your help fleablood :D